# Laravel, foreign key

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla de alumnos y otra tabla de documentos, tienen relación de 1:1
¿cómo puedo insertar un registro en documento en la cual me pide el id del alumno? para traerme el id de un alumno que ya existe y se inserte con ese id.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluir un [mcve] que permita comprender tu problema y lo que estás haciendo para resolverlo. Si buscas ideas, opiniones o recomendaciones, es mejor que uses Google. Actualmente tu pregunta es muy amplia y podría ser cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entendí tu pregunta. Obtienes el ID del alumno de acuerdo a una condición, por ejemplo:

`$id_alumno = Alumno::where("nombre","=","pepito")->value("id_alumno");`

Después insertas la fila del documento:

```
$documento = new Documento();
$documento->id_alumno = $id_alumno;
$documento->save();
```